# Move legend outside the chart area in C3.js

Tags: d3.js, legend, c3.js

Is there a way to put legend outside the chart area? I'm trying with `bindto` property, but it doesn't work ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ObCVxJNy3ehl0YvS0DIH?p=preview))

[Here is the example for amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/putting-a-legend-outside-the-chart-area/)

In [C3 documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html#legend-inset) there are only few positions allowed: top-left
top-right bottom-left bottom-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just re-parent it yourself:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var legend = d3.selectAll('.c3-legend-item');
  var svg = d3.select('#legend')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 640)
    .attr('height', 100);
  legend.each(function(){
    svg.node().appendChild(this);
  });
}, 100);
```

---

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SuScre46llMi9Tkj2WgH?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

You can probably solve this using:

```
legend: {
   show: false
}
```

And then adding a custom legend via C3 or D3

See http://c3js.org/samples/legend_custom.html for a working example